# Python adding integers in lists in specific order

Tags: python, list, sum

I'm trying to create a block of code where I can add two lists containing integers together.  That is if list a = [1,2,3] and list b = [4,5,6], then I would like to assign a list c that adds `(a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1], a[2]+b[2])` so that `c = [5,7,9]`.

This was my attempt but c remained an empty list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = []
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i == j:
            d = a[i]+b[j]
            e = c.append(d)
```

What should I change?

Comment: Yes, since `for i in a` will iterate over the *elements*, not the indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Iteration works over the *elements* of a list

If you write `for i in a`, you iterate over the *elements* of the list. So `j` will take the values `4`, `5` and `6`. And these will never match a value of `i`.

## Why the above is inefficient anyway

We can change it by using a `range`, we can write `for i in range(len(a))`, but this would be inefficient: we would iterate over every possible combination of one element of `a` and one of `b`. This would result in an *O(m n)* algorithm, with *m* the number of elements in `a`, and *n* the number of elements in `b`.

## The `zip(..)` function

To iterate through iterables concurrently, we can use `zip(..)`. `zip` takes as input one or more iterables. It will then construct tuples. So if we perform `zip(a, b)`, we will generate an iterable that will yield `(a[0], b[0])` followed by `(a[1], b[1])`, followed by `(a[2], b[2])` and so on.

## Imperative approach

So now we can rewrite it to:

```
c = []
for ai, bi in zip(a, b):
    c.append(ai + bi)
```

## List comprehension

This can be rewritten with *list comprehension* to:

```
c = [ai + bi for ai, bi in zip(a, b)]
```

## *More* functional programming approach

We can also use the `operator` module and use `operator.add` and `map` to write it in a more functional way:

```
from operator import add

c = list(map(add, a, b))
```

Since everything is rather dynamic however, it is important to note that it is not functional in the sense that objects in Haskell are mutuable, and we thus have no guarantees about the fact that there will be no side effects.

Comment: To be clear, the list comprehension approach is also a functional programming approach, and arguably one more in keeping with Python's general style.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: yes indeed, although the latter is more *functional* since we only make use of already defined functions. Furthermore there are no side effects (whereas there can technically be side effects in list comprehension, since you can override the same variable). The list comprehension is more *Python*, the last one is more *Haskell*,

Comment: Thanks a lot!  You lost me toward the end of the "Why the above is inefficient" section. In any case, as a beginner programmer, I just want to get things to work and hopefully I learn efficient methods later on. I haven't arrived at the level of understanding the "functional programming approach" section but maybe I will in the future.  Thanks, again. I will bookmark this page and study it. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: The list comprehension was borrowed from Haskell too. The `map` function is equally capable of triggering side-effects (and it's equally wrong to use it for that purpose), e.g. `c = []`, `list(map(c.append, map(add, a, b)))` works, with already defined functions, and it's awful, and there is nothing more or less functional about it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: not fully, since list comprehension in Haskell is actually syntactical sugar for a list monad, which can do more sophisticated things. For example in Python there is no such thing as a functor, or an applicative that can be applied on it. Sure there can also be side effects with `list(map(..))` since everything in Python is so dynamic. What I mean is that you can introduce what I would call "*syntactical side effects*". We can write for instance `a = [3, 4]; [x for _ in [1, 2] for x in a for a in [(1, 2)]]` in Python-2.x (that is why list comprehension "leaks" in Python-2.x).

Answer (score 9):

`zip()` will do the trick:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = []

for x, y in zip(a, b):
   c.append(x + y)
```

> [5, 7, 9]

Answer (score 4):

Here is another alternative using zip, the built in sum function, and list comprehension

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [ sum(x) for x in zip(a,b) ]
print c
```

Result is [5,7,9]

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

np.sum((a, b), axis=0)  # array([5, 7, 9])
```

Since OP is learning about python this isn't particularly useful. But I include it here to indicate how there are many ways to achieve the same goal.

[`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) is designed specifically for optimisation of numerical calculations.